# Suggestion to merge ergonomics and bike fit

Tags: feature-request, tagging

[ergonomics](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics) and [bike-fit](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bike-fit) seem too similar, and one does not have a wiki. Should they be merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. While there's probably some overlap, ergonomics and bike fit often times are not the same thing at all.

For example, there are mountain bike grips that are ergonomic, which has nothing to do with the way the bike fits. And roadies often choose a bike fit that emphasizes aerodynamics over ergonomics.